# R: How to append different text files with different column numbers?

Tags: r, weather

I have a series of datasets provided by MetOffice. The data depicts the UK Daily Rainfall Data and i have the data of Year 2008 - 2015. That is there are 9 text files. I want them to append one beneath each other to create a large dataset. That is i want to append the data of 2008 then 2009 then 2010 until 2016.

i imported the dataset into the R environment and want to concatenate all the dataset using the Base R can anyone help me here?

until now i have created a code to read the data like this:

```
setwd("C:/Useful Data/UK Daily Rainfall Data")
temp = list.files(pattern="*.txt")
for (i in 1:length(temp))
  assign(temp[i], read.table(temp[i],header = FALSE,sep=",",fill=TRUE))
```

this code has imported all the dataset with their original names. This can be depicted in the image below:

[image]

The main challenge here is also that all the datasets have different number of variables.

EDIT: Error after trying @akrun solution:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `rbindlist` from `library(data.table)` which also has the `fill` argument in case the number of columns are different in each dataset

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(lapply(temp, fread), use.names=TRUE, fill=TRUE, idcol=TRUE)
#   .id V1 V2 V3
#1:   1  1  2 NA
#2:   1  2  3 NA
#3:   1  3  4 NA
#4:   2  1 NA  6
#5:   2  2 NA  7
#6:   2  3 NA  8
#7:   2  4 NA  9
#8:   2  5 NA 10
```

#### data

```
d1 <- data.frame(V1= 1:3, V2= 2:4)
d2 <- data.frame(V1= 1:5, V3= 6:10)
lst <- list(d1, d2)
lapply(seq_along(lst), function(i) write.table(lst[[i]], 
    paste0('d', i, '.txt'), row.names=FALSE, quote=FALSE))

temp <- list.files(pattern="*.txt")
```

Comment: error sheet have been updated @akrun please have a look

Comment: @desmond.carros Have you used `use.names=TRUE` (just updated)

Comment: yes i have updated it simultaneously. But result is same.

Comment: @desmond.carros  I tried using a reproducible example and it is working fine for me.

Comment: @desmond.carros  In that case, can you try `lst <- lapply(temp, read.table, header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)` and see if there are errors.  THen, do `rbindlist(lst, use.names=TRUE, fill=TRUE, idcol=TRUE)`  Also, please specify the `sep=..` in the `read.table`

Comment: @desmond.carros Try `lst <- lapply(temp, read.table, sep=",", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`  You should change the `sep` depending upon the delimiter of the dataset.  After you have run this, check `str(lst)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104374/discussion-between-desmond-carros-and-akrun).